# what is the best approach to use same functions in different classes using php

Tags: php, oop

i have a service class written in php which called different classes to do same functions. In my each class, i am using the same functions for different clients. So every time a new client come to use my service, i just change the class name and the functions are remain same.

I have been trying to use the factory method pattern. But what i have figured out that if i use the factory method pattern, still i have to copy paste the same functions for different clients.

My scenario is i create a class to do the following.
   *For Client 1 functions are:
   setClient()
   process()*

*For Client 2 functions are:
   setClient()
   process()*

I know i can use interface or abstract class. But still i feel there are some problems as the setClient() and process() functions do exactly the same things.

**So what is the best approach to handle these type of scenarios?**

I don't want to write or copy paste the same functions again and again in different classes for different clients for the same purpose.

advance thanks to all participants.

Comment: Inheritence is the obvious method for child classes to inherit functions from a parent

Comment: Inherit an abstract class containing both functions

Comment: thanks Mark Baker and Ashwin Mukhijia..but the implementation logic is same! so how can i handle it? and i have to re-write the setClient() and Process() function in all child classes!! isn't it odd!?

Comment: If the functions do the same thing, they should be defined just once in the base class that all the concrete classes inherit from. That's the point of inheritance.

Comment: Every OO tutorial should have examples. If the normal pattern doesn't fit what you're doing, you should show your code so we can understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an abstract class and then extend it in your client class. lets define the abstract class first.

```
abstract class base {

     function common() {
           echo "common code here";
     } 
}
```

then inherit it for each client.

```
class clienta extends base {

      function clientAfunc() {
          $this->common(); //call common
      }
}
```

Comment: DevZer0 what OOP pattern is suitable in this scenario?

Comment: i am not sure of the pattern name but this is core behavior of OO